# Distinct with custom comparer

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Trying to use `Distinct()` using a custom comparer and it gives me the error:

> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

The `Default` comparer works fine but doesn't give the results I expect of course.  How can I fix this?

```
public class TimeEntryValidation
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeLocation { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeDepartment { get; set; }
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
}

public class MyRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<TimeEntryValidation>
{
    public bool Equals(TimeEntryValidation x, TimeEntryValidation y)
    {
        return (x.EmployeeDepartment == y.EmployeeDepartment && x.EmployeeLocation == y.EmployeeLocation);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TimeEntryValidation obj)
    {
        return obj.EmployeeID.GetHashCode(); 
    }
}

void Query(List<TimeEntryValidation> listToQuery)
{
    var groupedData =
        from oneValid in listToQuery
        group oneValid by oneValid.EmployeeID
            into g
        where g.Count() > 1
        select new {DoubleItems = g};
    var listItems = groupedData.Distinct(new MyRowComparer());
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of the error but... your comparer is broken since the results of the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods are unrelated. Any two items that are equal *must* have the same hashcode; this isn't necessarily the case using your comparer.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `groupedData` is some `IEnumerable<{an anonymous type}>` whereas `MyRowComparer` is `IEqualityComparer<TimeEntryValidation>`

It's unclear whether you intended `listItems` to be a list of groups, or whether you wanted the actual items themselves.

If it's the latter, you probably want something like this:

```
void Query(List<TimeEntryValidation> listToQuery)
{
    var groupedData = from oneValid in listToQuery
                        group oneValid by oneValid.EmployeeID
                            into g
                            where g.Count() > 1
                            select  g ;
    var listItems = groupedData.SelectMany(group => group).Distinct(new MyRowComparer());
    //listItems is now an IEnumerable<TimeEntryValidation>
}
```

Comment: I wanted the actual items, not the groups.

Comment: About LukeH's comment regarding GetHashCode()- should I return obj.ToString().GetHashCode(), my Equal is a bit more complicated than I posted here. Thank you to your both - LukeH and Davy8, appreciate it.